# REGEX - group - JAVA

Tags: regex

I want to do the following with only ONE regex pattern.
(I've got no access to program code, I can only insert a regex pattern)
I've got the text as input, e.g.

```
1000 lemons, 2 apples.
```

For the case "lemons" I want automatically the number of them,
for the case "apples" I want automatically the number of them.

With the regex pattern like

```
/\d+\s(apples)/
```

I would get the result

```
2 apples
```

But I want the result

```
2
```

with ONE regex pattern.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please share your code. You can use a capturing group around `\d+` rather than `apples`. Perhaps, all you need is `(\d+)\s*\w+`. Or `(\d+)\s*(?:apples?|lemons?)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But in this case I get the result "1000 lemons" ??!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

> I've got no access to program code, I can only insert a regex pattern

You need a positive lookahead-based regex (i.e. the part that should be checked for but discarded from the output must reside inside `(?=....)` construct):

```
\d+(?=\s*\w+)
```

or a bit more specific for your examples (if you need to match digits before specific words only)

```
\d+(?=\s*(?:apples?|lemons?))
```

See [regex demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/dL4mI3/2) and [demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/dL4mI3/1).

Since [*lookaheads*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) do not consume text, the text they match is not present in the output you get.

To only search for the number of lemons use

```
\d+(?=\s*lemons?)
```

Note that `?` makes the preceding character *optional* (matches 1 or 0 occurrences).

Comment: Okay, looks much better. But if i need only the numbers of lemons ??

Comment: Just keep the `lemons` in the lookahead - `\d+(?=\s*lemons?)`. The `?` at the end makes `s` optional. **AND** you may also enclose the words with `\b` word boundaries to *only match whole words*.

Comment: Great. Thank you :)